# What means the -z value in an if expression on a Linux script?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, if-statement, ubuntu-12.04

In this script I found this `if` expression:

```
if [ -z $1 ]; then
    echo "Usage: createpkg.sh <rev package>"
    exit
else
    CURRENT_VERSION=$1
fi
```

My problem is that I can't find what exactly means this `-z` value.

From the content of the echo I can deduct that (maybe) `$1` variable represents the sotware version. and that (maybe) `-z` is a void value. So if I execute the script without passing to it the version of the software that I would packing it print me the correct procedure to execute the script.

But I am not sure about the real meaning of the `-z` value.

Comment: As a side note, you should probably enclose your variable in quotes. `if [ -z "$1" ];`. I don't remember the exact reason (someone ?) but not doing so can result in unwanted behavior in some cases.

Comment: Yes, @Antoine_935, it will be problematic if the variable contains an space. It will become `if [ -z hello world ]` which `bash` won't be able to understand.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From `man test`:

```
   -z STRING
          the length of STRING is zero
```

So the condition:

```
if [ -z $1 ]; then
```

means "if the variable $1 is empty". Where `$1` is probably the first parameter of the script: if you execute it like `./script <parameter1> <parameter2>`, then `$1=parameter1`, `$2=parameter2` and so forth.

Comment: Yes, also I think that $1 is the firs parameter of my script but...where are definied the script parameter? how can I associate a parameter to a variable?

Comment: You have to check how the script is executed. If its name is "myscript.sh" then somewhere you will find a call `./myscript.sh param1 param2...` or `/bin/sh /path/to/myscript.sh param1 param2...`

Comment: I think that the script is executed in the shell with this command: createpkg.sh 2 (that create the package of the 2 version of the sofware) So the $1 variable is automatically bounded to the first parameter value (in this case: 2)?

Comment: Yes, exactly @AndreaNobili

Answer (score 6):

`help test` tells:

```
String operators:

  -z STRING      True if string is empty.
```

In your example, the script would print `Usage: createpkg.sh <rev package>` and exit if an argument was not supplied.

Comment: It's a shell built-in.  Type `type test` to verify!